# Connect to Bigtable emulator from localhost with Node.js client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to connect to Cloud Bigtable emulator from localhost. Saw couple of [posts](https://github.com/spotify/docker-bigtable) on how to connect to localhost Bigtable emulator with Java. There is no documentation that specifies how to do so with Node.js.

`@google-cloud/bigtable` client needs instance name while creating a connection. What should that be in case of localhost? Also what should be the project name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Using the Cloud Bigtable Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator#top_of_page) documentation:

> The emulator does not provide administrative APIs to create or manage instances and clusters. After the emulator starts up, you can connect to it using any project and instance name to create tables and read or write data.

Additionally, the Node.js Cloud Bigtable client supports the `BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment flag, which is documented in the [Using the Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator#using_the_emulator) section.